# Laravels syncWithoutDetaching and additional data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-5.8

I have Googled my fingers sore, and I can't see anyone discussing this, but I have a suspicion that Laravels `syncWithoutDetaching()` method doesn't take any parameters for extra data like `save()`, `sync()` and `attach()` does?

Does anybody know this? In the API documentation the method has the following parameters:

`array syncWithoutDetaching(Collection|Model|array $ids)`

I have trouble adding existing data to a relationship between a Guest and an Event. I need to add status for the guests and what event they are attending, maybe attending or declined.

Answer (score 9):

`sync()` and `syncWithoutDetaching()` both don't have a parameter for additional values, you have to pass the additional values as an array with the ids.

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

> You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:

```php
$user->roles()->sync([
    1 => ['expires' => true],
    2,
    3
]);
```

If you look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php#L70) you can see that `syncWithoutDetaching()` just calls `sync()` but passes `false` as the second argument.

In your case it would be something like this:

```php
$event->guests()->syncWithoutDetaching([
    1 => ['attending' => true],
    2 => ['attending' => false]
])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think @remul answer is the best, but it requires additions for people like me who get to this page.

`syncWithoutDetaching()` - is just an abbreviation for `sync()` - [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php#L71). This corresponds to `sync($data, false)`

The documentation [talks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) about another great method:

> If you would like to insert the same intermediate table values with
> each of the synced model IDs, you may use the `syncWithPivotValues`
> method

But the documentation does not say that the method accepts the third argument, which just corresponds to the logic of `syncWithoutDetaching()`.

Look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php#L135).
If you pass `false`, the IDs not passed will not be detaching.

I think this is what the question was about.